# Exit all instances of my app

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following function:

```
private void TakeOverAllScreens()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Screen s in Screen.AllScreens)
        {

            if (s != Screen.PrimaryScreen)
            {
                i++;
               Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath, "Screen|" + s.Bounds.X + "|" + s.Bounds.Y + "|" + i);
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see it creates a separate instance of my application for each screen on the pc.

How can I create an exit function that closes all of them?
The function needs to work on any instance of the app, not just my "Main" instance.

Comment: The `Process` class has an `Id` you might be able to use it to kill the process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can terminate all processes with the same name:

```
var current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
Process.GetProcessesByName(current.ProcessName)
    .Where(t => t.Id != current.Id)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(t => t.Kill());

current.Kill();
```

Comment: This is the code i used. Works like a charm. But not in debug, because the `ProcessName` is different in Debugging

Answer (score 4):

#### How can you close an application?

There are three general options:

- Kill it outright
- Assuming that it has a main window and that it behaves conventionally, send a `WM_CLOSE` message to that window by P/Invoking [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- Assuming that it wants to cooperate, use a custom communication channel to tell it to terminate itself

#### How should you close an application?

Killing a process outright is heavy-handed and should never be attempted unless you know that the process won't be doing anything sensitive when it's terminated. Typically this is used as a last resort.

Telling it to close its main window requires that you first learn what that window's `HWND` is somehow; you can do that by walking the list of top-level windows or by having the spawned process somehow communicate it to you. It also assumes that the other process will decide to terminate itself when you ask that its main window be closed (in reality it could decide to do anything, including completely ignore the message). This approach is a reasonable first attempt and it usually works fine with processes which are not under your control -- although you have to find the window yourself.

Using a custom communication channel allows you to completely control what happens and how plus it can be implemented in lots of ways, but it's an approach that involves writing the most code and needs you to have source access to both applications.

#### Conclusion

**It depends**. If you are 1000% sure that killing the process won't disrupt anything then that would be a quick and dirty solution; otherwise you need to use one of the two "polite" approaches.

Comment: The app only reads and displays data so killing it's cool. Besides i'm a fan of quick and dirty!

Answer (score 3):

Just you have to keep track of opened processes:

```
List<Process> opened = new List<Process>();

private void TakeOverAllScreens()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Screen s in Screen.AllScreens)
        {

            if (s != Screen.PrimaryScreen)
            {
                i++;
               opened.Add(Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath, "Screen|" + s.Bounds.X + "|" + s.Bounds.Y + "|" + i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Then:

```
private void terminateAll()
{
      foreach (var p in opened) p.Kill();
}
```

Comment: Would this work from any instance of the application, or only the "Main" instance?

Comment: Let me ask whether the new instances make in their turn new instances recursively?

Comment: No, only the Main instance creates new instances.

Comment: Yes. It should terminate all started processes by tha "main" process. For the main process, you can terminate it with `Application.Exit()`

Answer (score 1):

Put all opened process in list, so you can kill the process one by one. Look code bellow:

```
private void TakeOverAllScreens()
{
    int i = 0;
    List<Process> allProcesses = new List<Process>();
    foreach (Screen s in Screen.AllScreens)
    {
        if (s != Screen.PrimaryScreen)
        {
            i++;
           allProcesses.Add(Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath, "Screen|" + s.Bounds.X + "|" + s.Bounds.Y + "|" + i));
        }
    }

    foreach (Process proc in allProcesses)
    {
        proc.Kill();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
void ExitAll(string processName)
{
    foreach(Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (p.ProcessName.ToLower().Equals(processName.ToLower()))
            p.Kill();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I always execute command

```
tskill notepad // to kill all instances of notepad
```

From within App, it can be done like

```
Process.Start("cmd /k tskill " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName)
```